# Home page RequestMapping. Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I try to get all avaliable groups from db when i load start page. Btu I can't set correct RequestMapping for home page and when i load home page it does load any data to JSP page. I try to set it as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newStudentForm() {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(""); 

    mav.getModelMap().put("allGroups", gss.selectAllGroups()); // add all available groups

    return mav;
}
```

but i'm not sure that i set correct 'value = "/"' and name in ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("");

Here's my xml file with all settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     id="WebApp_ID"
     version="3.0">

  <display-name>IRSystem</display-name>

  <!-- The start page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>IRSystemServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/IRSystemServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>IRSystemServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

IRSystemServlet-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd

                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Set packages to scan for necessary components-->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.irs.controllers"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.irs.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.irs.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.irs.entitis"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- JDBC DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:VLAD-PC/@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
    <property name="username" value="VLAD"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</value>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.irs.entities"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- set response encoding UTF-8 -->
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Hibernate transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

How should i do it to get all data i need to JSP page when i Load it?

Comment: please provide the content of IRSystemServlet-servlet.xml

Comment: I have added IRSystemServlet-servlet.xml

Answer (score 4):

You have set your home page in ModelAndView object something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newStudentForm() {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index"); 

    mav.getModelMap().put("allGroups", gss.selectAllGroups()); // add all available groups

    return mav;
}
```

you don't need to have welcome page as the moment you hit **/** it will call the above method.
delete this code

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to return the view name in your controller.
since you configured the InternalResourceViewResolver with prefix /WEB-INF/jsp/ and suffix .jsp you should return `index` to get `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`  as view.

`ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your workflow as below:

Basically your web application will look into welcome page and /redirect is fired which is captured by controller and execute the logic to get all available groups from DB and show in the startup page.

In web.xml add the following code and drop the `startup.jsp` in webapp directory.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>startup.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In `startup.jsp` , add below code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:redirect url="/redirect"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally in the `Controller` , you could add the code below:

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String runMethod(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
       // add your logic to fetch all groups 
     return "results"; // return results.jsp where it has all the groups
    }
}
```